# To follow a prepositional phrase with an imperative one

Tags: grammaticality, idiomatic-language, prepositional-phrases

> Except for Louisa, who’s away in Berlin this weekend, we’ll all be at the party.

The first sentence is from Cambridge dictionary and hence I know it is correct.

> **Fruits:** Except for apples, eat them only on Thursdays.

I'm wondering whether the second one OK. Is it grammatically correct and idiomatic to follow a prepositional phrase ("except for apples") with an imperative one ("eat them only on Thursdays)?

I don't actually care about apples and Thursdays, of course. This is just an example.

Comment: Your sentence does not make sense as we do not know what them refers to. The prepositional phrase is not the problem per se. Except for the barn doors, close all other doors. [see?] But normally, it would be: Close all doors except for the barn doors.

Comment: @Lambie If "Fruits" is a section header, is it a bad idea to start the section itself that way? Isn't it clear that "them" points to "Fruits"?

Comment: **Fruit: Eat only on Fridays except for apples**. Best not to use an s on fruit here. If this is for medical instructions, for example. You wouldn't say: Don't drink coffees...You would say: Don't drink coffee.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normal order of words:

- Except for bananas, eat all the fruit on your plate.

VERSUS

- Eat all the fruit on your plate except for bananas.

Both are correct.

There is no rule that says you can't preposition a prepositional phrase.